# Surrounding every word in a wordpress post with link

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

For an art project I need a routine (I think in Javascript) to sourround every word in a wordpress post with a link of itself and ".com" added, for example:

the words: my big belly

should become

```
<a href="my.com">my</a>&nbsp;<a href="big.com">big</a>&nbsp;<a href="belly.com">belly</a>
```

How should I do this in javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `.replace(/(\w+)/, '<a href="$1.com">$1</a>')`

Comment: sorry. new here. corrected the mistake.